# What does a negative stockholder's deficit mean?

Tags: united-states, investing

I know negative stockholder's equity means that theres more liabilities than assets but what does a negative stockholder's deficit mean?

Comment: can you provide a quote and source that includes it?

Comment: At a literal level, a _negative_ deficit would be a _positive_ surplus (but it would be a strange way of describing a surplus). As mhoran_psprep says, you need to [edit] your question to give some context.